# How to write a query to find all tables in HIVE db that have a specific column name

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I've got a database with about 100 tables and I need to build a join query to get specific data from two of them. I know one but not the other. Basically I need something like:

```
select <tables> from <HIVE_database> where exists table.column name;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a shell script to search for the column among all tables.

The first line gives you all the table names. It is passed to read command 
and output of describe from each table is searched for the column name.

```
$hive -e 'show tables in <HIVE_database>'  | \
while read line
do
 echo "TABLE NAME : $line"
  eval "hive -e 'describe <HIVE_database>.$line'" | grep "<column_name>" 
done
```